# Sending different data from different method on same route - laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

[image]

I am trying to get **order data** in **order tab** and **profile details data** in **profile tab**.

Is it possible to achieve ???

If Yes, then please tell me how ?

If No, then please tell me, laravel is the most advance framework of PHP, why we can't send multiple data from multiple methods in same View ?

Controller

```
public function GetOrders()
{
    $gtord = DB::table('orders')->where('email',Session::get('email'))->get();

    return view('/my-account')->with('gtord',$gtord);
}

public function ProfileEdit() 
{
    $data = DB::table('customers')->where('email',Session::get('email'))->first();

    return view('/my-account')->with('data',$data);
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/my-account', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@ProfileEd');

Route::get('/my-account', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@GetOrders');
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: when i run project, it throws **$data is undefined**.
when i comment 1st route, it throws **$data is undefined**
when i comment 2nd route, it throws **$gtord is undefined**

Comment: You can't have 2 Routes with the same URL and Method

Comment: This would be a case for js. You can load all data and change the tabs with js or it would be better if you load the data with axios.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple routes with the same 'signature', ie method and url.

If you're just showing/hiding tabs using JS, what you can do is return the view with two variables, eg:

```php
public function AccountView()
{
    $data = DB::table('customers')->where('email',Session::get('email'))->first();
    $gtord = DB::table('orders')->where('email',Session::get('email'))->get();

    return view('/my-account')->with(['data' => $data, 'gtord' => $gtord]);
}
```

And then just use one route:

```
Route::get('/my-account', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@AccountView');
```

If the two tabs are different urls, or you're using Vue or similar you would have two distinct routes with different signatures.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't have 2 same routes with the same method. It's quite logical and necessary. Otherwise, the whole routing system would collapse.

On the other hand, you can have a function in the controller, and call the other functions to collect data.

```
// web.php

Route::get('/my-account', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@index');
```

```
// controller
public function index()
{
    $orders = $this->getOrders();
    $profile = $this->getProfiles();

    return view('yourView', compact(['orders', 'profile']));
}

public function getOrders()
{
   // 
}


public function getProfiles()
{
   // 
}
```

BTW, it's a better practice to move custom function to models, services or traits, and keep only the functions of 7 verbs in the contoller.